# VirtualBox: How can I expose apps inside VirtualBox's VM to the internet on Windows 11 (so people can visit it from a domain)?

Tags: networking, router, virtualbox, port-forwarding, iis

- I have a domain name `app.example.com`, pointing at my internet's public, static IP.
- I have a computer running Windows 11 with the internal IP of `192.168.192.168`.
- On that computer, I have a VM (VirtualBox, Ubuntu) with NAT and an internal IP of `10.10.10.10`.
- The VM has an app that is running on port `1234`.

**Questions: How do I expose the app to the internet, so that when people visit `app.example.com`, they can see the app inside the VM? I'm trying with IIS but so far no luck. Is there any better alternative to IIS?**

What I have done:

- I created a port forwarding rule for the VM that forwards any Host that is listening to `:1234` to the VM `10.10.10.10:1234`. At this point, I can access the app inside the VM from the Host by running `localhost:1234`. I can also access the app from other computers in the same network by using the Host's internal IP, e.g. `192.168.192.168:1234`.
- I opened port `80` on my router settings so traffic from `app.example.com` can go through. I also opened the firewall on the Host to accept all incoming traffics (just for testing purposes).
- In IIS on the Host, I created a binding with the domain `app.example.com`, IP `127.0.0.1` and
  port `1234`.

I still cannot access `app.example.com` from outside the network and my network knowledge is limited so I don't know what else I should do.

Answer (score 1):

Put the machine you wish to access into Bridged Mode so that external computers can access it.

[Virtual Box Bridged Mode](https://docs.oracle.com/en/virtualization/virtualbox/6.0/user/network_bridged.html#:%7E:text=To%20enable%20bridged%20networking%2C%20open,network%20interfaces%20of%20your%20systems.)

> To enable bridged networking, open the Settings dialog of a virtual
> machine, go to the Network page and select Bridged Network in the
> drop-down list for the Attached To field. Select a host interface from
> the list at the bottom of the page, which contains the physical
> network interfaces of your systems.

This will give your machine an IP on the router so people on the domain can get to it.

I do this to access guest machines from an external machine.

Remember (depending on your overall setup) you may wish to / need to address this guest machine by IP address, at least to start.

Comment: So I used bridged Mode, and the VM now has an internal IP of, say, 192.168.111.111. Within the network, I can access my app by visiting 192.168.111.111:1234. I also edited IIS binding to listen to app.example.com and forward it to http://192.168.111.111:1234. However, the app still cannot be accessed outside of my network. Are there any other settings I might have missed? Or would you recommend a tool to trace the requests and see if it reaches my computer? Thank you!

Comment: You can use WIreshark or an app like that.  You can also use NET USE to connect a folder or drive.